# Interior of a closed interval in infinite-interval topology

Tags: general-topology

Consider $X:=[0,\infty)$, equipped with the topology generated by intervals of the form $[a,+\infty)$, $a\geq 0$. In my topology text this is called the Arrow topology but I think this is nonstandard.

We wish to determine $\text{Int}[0,1]$. My conjecture is that it is $\varnothing$, since no open set is contained in $[0,1]$. Is this argument correct? It feels unusual to say the interior is empty with such a "nonempty" set.

Comment: As suggested by the posted answer, you would have said "no *non-empty* open set is contained in $[0,1]$." It feels unusual, but one perhaps could explain that with the topology being unusual (e.g., it is $T_0$ but not even $T_1$).

Comment: $\Bbb P$ (the irrationals in the reals) also has empty interior in the reals, even though it's "almost all points". So it happens frequently "in real life" too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument is almost correct. The interior of $[0,1]$ is empty because $\emptyset$ is the only open subset of $[0,1]$.